# how to get all the element within a pandas column multiplied together?

Tags: python, pandas, multiplication

For example, m is a pandas dataframe:

```
m

5    9
2    5
1    3
Name: label, dtype: int64
```

I want to have 9*5*3 = 135

similar as row sum, want to do a row multiply. 
tried dat.rmul, dat.mul, dat.muliply. It seems none of them can do it.

thanks!

Comment: This isn't a dataframe, it's a series with a name "label".

Comment: `df['col_name'].prod()` or `df.prod()` - for all numeric columns?

Comment: ^ or `np.prod(df['col_name'])`